# $\frac {\sin x - 1}{\sin x - 2}+\frac{1}2 \ge \frac {2-\sin x}{3 - \sin x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've tried Cauchy, subtracting RHS from LHS, but can't solve it. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-\sin x}{2-\sin x}-\frac{2-\sin x}{3-\sin x}+\frac12$$

$$=\frac{(1-\sin x)(3-\sin x)-(2-\sin x)^2}{(2-\sin x)(3-\sin x)}+\frac12$$

$$=\frac{-1}{(2-\sin x)(3-\sin x)}+\frac12$$

$$=\frac{-2+(2-\sin x)(3-\sin x)}{(2-\sin x)(3-\sin x)}$$

$$=\frac{(4-\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{(2-\sin x)(3-\sin x)}\ge0$$

as $\sin x\ge-1$ for real $x,1-\sin x\ge0$ and $r-\sin x>0$ for real $r>1$

Comment: thanks. was your comment invalid or was it the same as this solution, just a little different?

Comment: @SabitAman, I should say, the comment was partial hint